# SIP client alternative to Facetime?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, facetime

Wikipedia says:

"Like the video version, FaceTime Audio is currently only available between Apple devices."

So...I was going to ask how to make/receive SIP calls from Facetime...but that's not an option.

what's a free SIP client for Mac OS x laptops?

Comment: what is SIP ? is it same as VOIP

Comment: @Buscar웃 it's a specific VOIP protocol.  There are different VoIP protocols.  FaceTime uses SIP.  However, while with most SIP clients, you can call other SIP clients, FaceTime allows you to contact only other FaceTime users, not all SIP users.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options but most of them have not been updated, I would check out Jitsi, formerly known as Sip Communicator (I think). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with Telephone from the App Store and then once you have some more detailed requirements, you could refine what you're looking for.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/telephone/id406825478?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Linphone](http://www.linphone.org), a free and open source client. I've tried it recently and it works.

Linphone also offers a [free SIP service](https://www.linphone.org/free-sip-service.html) if you would like to create an account with them (but you can register with any other SIP service provider and still use the Linphone software).